# How to read .pkl file in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dictionary saved in .pkl format using the following code in python 3.X

```
import pickle as cpick 
OutputDirectory="My data file path"
with open("".join([OutputDirectory, 'data.pkl']), mode='wb') as fp:
cpick.dump(data_dict, fp, protocol=cpick.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

I want to read this file in pyspark. Can you suggest me how to do that? Currently I'm using spark 2.0 & python 2.7.13

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: Experts, please suggest. I need it urgently

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40485730/7045987) out.